Installation of mysql2 0.5.6 ruby gem in Windows 10 fails
an attempt to install 'mysql2' gem in Windows 10 fails. I did some search on internet and tried multiple suggestions without success.
As suggested in mysql2 gem documentation the MySQL Connector/C downloaded and unarchived into c:\MySQL directory.
Then a command was issued
gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- '--with-mysql-dir=c:\MySQL\mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-winx64'

what has produced following output
C:\WINDOWS\system32>gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- '--with-mysql-dir=c:\MySQL\mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-winx64'
Using rubygems directory: C:/Users/John Smith/.gem/ruby/3.3.0
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Installing required msys2 packages: mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libmariadbclient
error: failed to init transaction (unable to lock database)
error: could not lock database: Permission denied
pacman failed with the following output:
Building native extensions with: '--with-mysql-dir=c:\MySQL\mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-winx64'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/Users/John Smith/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.6/ext/mysql2
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb --with-mysql-dir\=c:\\MySQL\\mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-winx64
checking for rb_absint_size()... yes
checking for rb_absint_singlebit_p()... yes
checking for rb_gc_mark_movable()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_enc_interned_str() in ruby.h... yes
-----
Using --with-mysql-dir=c:\MySQL\mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-winx64
-----
checking for -lmysqlclient... no
checking for mysql.h... yes
checking for errmsg.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_DISABLED in mysql.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_PREFERRED in mysql.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_REQUIRED in mysql.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_VERIFY_CA in mysql.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_VERIFY_IDENTITY in mysql.h... yes
checking for MYSQL.net.vio in mysql.h... yes
checking for MYSQL.net.pvio in mysql.h... no
checking for MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH in mysql.h... yes
checking for MYSQL_ENABLE_CLEARTEXT_PLUGIN in mysql.h... yes
checking for SERVER_QUERY_NO_GOOD_INDEX_USED in mysql.h... yes
checking for SERVER_QUERY_NO_INDEX_USED in mysql.h... yes
checking for SERVER_QUERY_WAS_SLOW in mysql.h... yes
checking for MYSQL_OPTION_MULTI_STATEMENTS_ON in mysql.h... yes
checking for MYSQL_OPTION_MULTI_STATEMENTS_OFF in mysql.h... yes
checking for my_bool in mysql.h... yes
checking for mysql_ssl_set() in mysql.h... no
-----
Setting rpath to /lib
-----
creating Makefile

current directory: C:/Users/John Smith/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.6/ext/mysql2
make DESTDIR\= sitearchdir\=./.gem.20240624-23736-20lfro sitelibdir\=./.gem.20240624-23736-20lfro clean

current directory: C:/Users/John Smith/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.6/ext/mysql2
make DESTDIR\= sitearchdir\=./.gem.20240624-23736-20lfro sitelibdir\=./.gem.20240624-23736-20lfro
generating mysql2-x64-mingw-ucrt.def
compiling client.c
compiling infile.c
compiling mysql2_ext.c
compiling result.c
compiling statement.c
linking shared-object mysql2/mysql2.so
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x1f3): undefined reference to `mysql_send_query'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x256): undefined reference to `mysql_options'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x279): undefined reference to `mysql_options'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x29c): undefined reference to `mysql_options'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x2bf): undefined reference to `mysql_options'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x2e2): undefined reference to `mysql_options'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x32b): undefined reference to `mysql_real_connect'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x3a9): undefined reference to `mysql_options4'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x3cd): undefined reference to `mysql_init'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x4a1): undefined reference to `mysql_session_track_get_first'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x4de): undefined reference to `mysql_session_track_get_next'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x54f): undefined reference to `mysql_session_track_get_first'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x58e): undefined reference to `mysql_session_track_get_next'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x5e6): undefined reference to `mysql_get_ssl_cipher'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x646): undefined reference to `mysql_info'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x6a5): undefined reference to `mysql_warning_count'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x6dd): undefined reference to `mysql_use_result'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x6fd): undefined reference to `mysql_store_result'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x725): undefined reference to `mysql_more_results'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x768): undefined reference to `mysql_set_server_option'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x79c): undefined reference to `mysql_select_db'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x7b5): undefined reference to `mysql_ping'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x7d5): undefined reference to `mysql_read_query_result'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x84b): undefined reference to `mysql_get_server_version'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x86b): undefined reference to `mysql_get_server_info'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x980): undefined reference to `mysql_get_client_info'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x9c4): undefined reference to `mysql_get_client_version'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0xa50): undefined reference to `mysql_get_client_version'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0xa57): undefined reference to `mysql_get_client_info'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0xab5): undefined reference to `mysql_options'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0xbc9): undefined reference to `mysql_thread_id'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0xca9): undefined reference to `mysql_insert_id'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0xd1e): undefined reference to `mysql_error'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0xd32): undefined reference to `mysql_sqlstate'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0xd79): undefined reference to `mysql_errno'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0xdf5): undefined reference to `mysql_next_result'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0xe1c): undefined reference to `mysql_more_results'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0xe34): undefined reference to `mysql_free_result'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0xe7d): undefined reference to `mysql_affected_rows'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0xef9): undefined reference to `mysql_next_result'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x1058): undefined reference to `mysql_options'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x10b0): undefined reference to `mysql_get_server_version'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x1154): undefined reference to `mysql_options'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x1193): undefined reference to `mysql_options'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x11e7): undefined reference to `mysql_options'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x1355): undefined reference to `mysql_close'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x143d): undefined reference to `mysql_errno'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x14e8): undefined reference to `mysql_options'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x1514): undefined reference to `mysql_error'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x1820): undefined reference to `mysql_escape_string'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x191f): undefined reference to `mysql_real_escape_string'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x19f5): undefined reference to `mysql_close'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x1afd): undefined reference to `mysql_options'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x1b42): undefined reference to `mysql_error'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x1d4d): undefined reference to `mysql_errno'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x1e19): undefined reference to `mysql_options'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x1e3d): undefined reference to `mysql_error'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x1ef7): undefined reference to `mysql_options'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x1f1b): undefined reference to `mysql_error'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x1fd2): undefined reference to `mysql_options'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x1ff5): undefined reference to `mysql_error'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x20b2): undefined reference to `mysql_options'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x20d5): undefined reference to `mysql_error'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x2192): undefined reference to `mysql_options'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x21b5): undefined reference to `mysql_error'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x2269): undefined reference to `mysql_options'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x2295): undefined reference to `mysql_error'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x236b): undefined reference to `mysql_options'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x2390): undefined reference to `mysql_error'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x2490): undefined reference to `mysql_options'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x24b5): undefined reference to `mysql_error'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x25f5): undefined reference to `mysql_close'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x2627): undefined reference to `mysql_get_client_info'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: client.o:client.c:(.text+0x2697): undefined reference to `mysql_server_init'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: infile.o:infile.c:(.text+0x1cb): undefined reference to `mysql_set_local_infile_handler'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: result.o:result.c:(.text+0x6a): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_num_rows'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: result.o:result.c:(.text+0xb5): undefined reference to `mysql_num_rows'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: result.o:result.c:(.text+0x16d): undefined reference to `mysql_num_fields'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: result.o:result.c:(.text+0x1ac): undefined reference to `mysql_fetch_field_direct'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: result.o:result.c:(.text+0x295): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_fetch'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: result.o:result.c:(.text+0x3a6): undefined reference to `mysql_free_result'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: result.o:result.c:(.text+0x3d5): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_free_result'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: result.o:result.c:(.text+0x75b): undefined reference to `mysql_fetch_fields'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: result.o:result.c:(.text+0x7b3): undefined reference to `mysql_error'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: result.o:result.c:(.text+0x874): undefined reference to `mysql_fetch_fields'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: result.o:result.c:(.text+0x998): undefined reference to `mysql_data_seek'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: result.o:result.c:(.text+0x9e6): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_num_rows'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: result.o:result.c:(.text+0xa65): undefined reference to `mysql_num_rows'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: result.o:result.c:(.text+0xba2): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_bind_result'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: result.o:result.c:(.text+0xe15): undefined reference to `mysql_num_fields'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: result.o:result.c:(.text+0x215d): undefined reference to `mysql_num_fields'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: result.o:result.c:(.text+0x21a0): undefined reference to `mysql_fetch_field_direct'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: result.o:result.c:(.text+0x221d): undefined reference to `mysql_num_fields'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: result.o:result.c:(.text+0x26f7): undefined reference to `mysql_fetch_lengths'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: result.o:result.c:(.text+0x3b41): undefined reference to `mysql_num_fields'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: result.o:result.c:(.text+0x3f19): undefined reference to `mysql_num_fields'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: result.o:result.c:(.text+0x3f58): undefined reference to `mysql_fetch_field_direct'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: result.o:result.c:(.text+0x3fc5): undefined reference to `mysql_fetch_field_direct'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: result.o:result.c:(.text+0x4045): undefined reference to `mysql_num_fields'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: result.o:result.c:(.text+0x4075): undefined reference to `mysql_num_fields'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: result.o:result.c:(.text+0x231): undefined reference to `mysql_fetch_row'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: statement.o:statement.c:(.text+0x22): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_close'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: statement.o:statement.c:(.text+0x53): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_prepare'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: statement.o:statement.c:(.text+0x75): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_execute'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: statement.o:statement.c:(.text+0x181): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_insert_id'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: statement.o:statement.c:(.text+0x1f1): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_field_count'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: statement.o:statement.c:(.text+0x251): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_param_count'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: statement.o:statement.c:(.text+0x2b8): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_close'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: statement.o:statement.c:(.text+0x2f8): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_close'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: statement.o:statement.c:(.text+0x355): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_error'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: statement.o:statement.c:(.text+0x369): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_sqlstate'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: statement.o:statement.c:(.text+0x3dd): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_errno'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: statement.o:statement.c:(.text+0x455): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_affected_rows'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: statement.o:statement.c:(.text+0x520): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_result_metadata'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: statement.o:statement.c:(.text+0x534): undefined reference to `mysql_fetch_fields'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: statement.o:statement.c:(.text+0x53f): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_field_count'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: statement.o:statement.c:(.text+0x5a1): undefined reference to `mysql_free_result'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: statement.o:statement.c:(.text+0x5fc): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_errno'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: statement.o:statement.c:(.text+0x6e2): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_param_count'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: statement.o:statement.c:(.text+0x83e): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_result_metadata'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: statement.o:statement.c:(.text+0x85d): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_store_result'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: statement.o:statement.c:(.text+0x905): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_attr_set'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: statement.o:statement.c:(.text+0xbfb): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_bind_param'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: statement.o:statement.c:(.text+0xed5): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_errno'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: statement.o:statement.c:(.text+0x11db): undefined reference to `mysql_free_result'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: statement.o:statement.c:(.text+0x1289): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_init'
C:/bin/Ruby33-x64/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: statement.o:statement.c:(.text+0x12ba): undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_attr_set'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:265: mysql2.so] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Users/John Smith/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.6 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Users/John Smith/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.3.0/mysql2-0.5.6/gem_make.out

It looks like compilation stage is successful but linker fails to build a library file. It is not clear why linker (collect2.exe) does not find reference to subroutines defined in libmysql.dll library of MySQL Connector/C.
I have used Dependencies to verify referenced subroutines in the library file and puzzled why it fails to link.
In the mysql2 documentation it is mentioned that without specifying --with-mysql-dir option gem installer suppose to download connector but it does not happen.
Is there a soul who recently was able successfully install mysql2 gem in Windows 10?
Thank you in advance for your assistance in resolution of this issue.
Polar Bear

After some reseach on internet the following solution of the issue was found.
Run cmd as administrator and install libmariadbclient library
C:> ridk exec pacman -Ss mariadb
C:> ridk exec pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-libmariadbclient

Download and install git for windows, obtain mysql2 0.5.6 from github
mkdir c:\x
C:> cd c:\x
C:\x> git clone https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2.git 
C:\x> cd mysql2
C:\x\mysql2> git checkout 0.5.6

Edit C:\x\mysql\ext\client.c and comment out lines 1541-1543
// if (lib[i] != MYSQL_LINK_VERSION[i]) {
//   rb_raise(rb_eRuntimeError, "Incorrect MySQL client library version! This gem was compiled for %s but the client library is %s.", MYSQL_LINK_VERSION, lib);
// }

Save client.c file, build mysql2 gem and install it
C:\x\mysql2> gem build mysql2.gemspec
  Successfully built RubyGem
  Name: mysql2
  Version: 0.5.6
  File: mysql2-0.5.6.gem

C:\x\mysql2> gem install mysql2-0.5.6.gem -- --with-mysql-dir=c:\MySQL\mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-winx64

Run a test ruby script (adopt it to match your DB and data table)
require 'mysql2'

# Connect to MySQL server
client = Mysql2::Client.new(
  host: 'your_db_host',
  username: 'your_db_user',
  password: 'your_db_password',
  database: 'your_db_database'
)

# Execute a query
results = client.query('SELECT * FROM your_db_table')

# Print the results
results.each do |row|
  puts "%3d %-12s %2d %3d" % row.values_at('id','title','value','count')
end

# Close the connection
client.close

Bellow ruby script output for my test db_table
C:\Users\John Smith\Documents\work\ruby\mysql>test.rb
  1 some_name     1  12
  2 his_name      2  10
  3 her_name      3   8
  4 Grandmother   4   5
  5 Son           7   5
  6 Daughter      8   9
  7 Отец          3   8

This information is provided to be publicly available in hope that some ruby newbes will save reseach time when they come accross mysql2 gem installation issue.
Polar Bear
